# highcharts: margin between two boxplot series

Tags: highcharts, padding, boxplot

I have a Highcharts chart containing boxplots. The chart has 1 yaxis and 1 series containing 4 data-arrays which all are on the same yaxis, obviously.

how can i increase the padding between Series[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WAK1.png) and Series[2]? the x-axis is based on categories.

[image]

**EDIT:**
of course, i tried already with groupPadding/pointpadding, but couldn't get it to work. if i apply point/groupPadding to one specific array in series then its width gets smaller. if apply it to the whole series, then the padding is between each of the boxplots. however, i only need the padding between Series[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WAK1.png) and Series[2]. are there any other ways to try?

**EDIT2:**
updated/changed picture.

Comment: If the intent is to group them, you can also set this up as two series and use categories: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/zf7bcmf5/

Comment: i already use categories, so i think i cannot reuse them for grouping, but thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pointPlacemet`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.boxplot.pointPlacement) for each of the series. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lftuhzk/

```
    series: [{
        pointPlacement: -0.1, // to the left
        data: [ ... ]
    }, {
        pointPlacement: -0.1, // to the left
        data: [ ... ]
    }, {
        pointPlacement: 0.1, // to the right
        data: [ ... ]
    }, {
        pointPlacement: 0.1, // again, to the right
        data: [ ... ] 
    }]
```